# Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method, android studio

Tags: android-studio

i try everything to fix it nothing work please help me

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_cphs46tz268dmjxqvce03wwfv.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_cphs46tz268dmjxqvce03wwfv$_run_closure1) values: [build_cphs46tz268dmjxqvce03wwfv$_run_closure1@1629e22]
```

Answer (score 0):

In app's build gradle , you may add ndk's abiFilters in a wrong place like this:

```
android {
  defaultConfig{
    ...
  }
  ...
  ndk {
      abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
  }
}
```

try to add ndk in defaultConfig like this:

```
android {
  defaultConfig{
    ...
    ndk {
      abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
    } 
  }
}
```